# Risk factor analysis in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, sharding, risk-analysis

I am trying to make mongodb set-up, I am trying to analyze risk factor involved in it.

My configuration  in testing environment is

```
Routing server------> Config Server ------- > Shard01
                                              Shard02
                                              Shard03
```

My routing server and config server is running on same machine. Shard01, Shard02, Shard03 are running on three different machine respectively. I want to analyze what all risk factors are involved in this system. For example, one scenario is if any  Shard machine is down application will stop?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is a Very Bad Idea (TM) to have only one config server. For production environments, always, *always*, ***always*** use three config servers. Reason: Without a config server, the cluster basically becomes useless, since the query router gets the information about which key range lives on which shard from the config servers. (Setting aside mongos' metadata caching, as this only delays the problem). *Note: If doing otherwise, proceed at your own risk.*
2. It is a very bad idea to have the config server and the query router running on the same machine. Under heavy load, these machines need to compete for network IO. While this is a rare case, it still might happen. It makes (a lot) more sense to put a query router on each application server: it reduces the network latency (one hop less until the data is reached), the individual mongos can't be overloaded and you don't need to run your mongos on the config server. ;) Seriously, it is the suggested and well proven setup.
3. It is an ***AWFUL*** idea to run a shard as a standalone instance. If your primary shard (the shard holding the unsharded collections, including `system`) fails, you are in big trouble. You should ***always*** use replica sets as shards. *Note: If doing otherwise, proceed at your own risk.*

A less well known feature of the MongoDB drivers is that you can configure them to use multiple mongos instances. If the first one fails, the next one is tried. So, with multiple mongos (one per application server), proper data source configuration, three config servers and replica sets as shards there is no single point of failure (node wise).

Comment: What if my one shard machine is down? Say shard01 machine is down. Will my setup still work?

Comment: If a shard consist of a standard replica set, yes. If you use standalone mongods, approximately 1/3 of the sharded data will be unavailable. If you primary shard for a DB goes down, the DB basically becomes unusable. As I have written. Hence: Always use a replica set for a shard.

Comment: I don't understood it properly, you said, "If a shard consist of a standard replica set" and again "Always use a replica set for a shard". It looks contradictory.